# For which $n$'s $2^n\mid n!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> I am trying to find for which natural numbers $2^n$ divides $n!$.

This is similar to asking for which $n$, $\nu_2(n!) \geq n$, where $\nu_2$ is the 2-adic valuation.

I am pretty stuck on finding these $n$'s. I have tried for example $n=10$ and it didn't divide $10!$.

I have tried to work with the Legendre formula but achieved no progression

Comment: $2^{n-1}$ divides $n!$ when $n$ is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 4):

$2^n$ never divides $n!$ because

$$\nu_2(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor} \Big\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \Big\rfloor <  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^k} = n.$$

*Edit:* Here, $n>0$.

Comment: You used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula.